# Is it possible to have PHP if statement with all variables?

Tags: php, if-statement

Simple question really. I have come across an issue with work where it would be ideal to store >= <= and == into a variable to spit out into certain if statements wherever the case may be.

```
$numb1 = 5
$numb2 = 10
$option = >=

if($numb1 $option $numb2)
```

Comment: Considered to use if/elseif/elseif?

Comment: That's what I am currently doing however I was wondering if there was another option. Currently I am saying...

    if $option = '=='
    if $numb1 == $numb2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a var for testing this in a control instruction.
This will return some : `syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE`

You could use some eval() to do it, but it's not advisable.

Perhap's you could make something different with the following :

```
$option=$_GET['option']; // or POST or something else...
$numb1 = 5;
$numb2 = 10;

switch($option) {
 case ">=":
    if($numb1 >= $numb2){//someting}
    break;
 case "<=":
    if($numb1 <= $numb2){//someting}
    break;
 case "==":
    if($numb1 == $numb2){//someting}
    break;
 default://something else if there is no $option
    break;
}
```

Or with a function like the following

```
function testVar($numb1,$numb2,$option)
{
   // Same switch
}
```

Comment: I have yet to use switch, although I am checking it out atm.

Comment: However what is the advantage to use this over the regular IF/ELSEIF statements?

Comment: It's cleaner for me in this case. With if() and elseif() you'll have less visibility with nested if(){if()}elseif{if()}...

Comment: Alright I am good with that. It's worth getting used to at least and with the same functionality. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not without using `eval()` which is generally considered a bad idea

Comment: How would that work? Also why is it considered a bad idea? As it stands I have < > == stored in sql and I do checks to first see which it is then proceed with the right if statement

Comment: You have to be very careful to ensure that eval can never take in user input. Even if you're 100% sure you, it's still safer to use switches and if-else structures, rather than running the risk.  What if down the track someone sees your function and thinks "That looks handy" and doesn't realise the potential consequences of eval() so they send user input into the function as one of the paramaters...

Comment: The variables that would be used for the eval() are static and set by a select list then stored in sql. Therefore I know exactly what will be in the statement I think.

Comment: As below, select boxes aren't as secure as people think. They can still be manipulated client side using Firebug or something like that. You still need to perform some validation on the server side for select boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it directly like that, will only work using [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_eval.asp) - Using eval is not considered good practice. The main problem being that if the eval() statements takes in user input the user can inject php into your code. That's obviously bad. Refer this thread - [When is eval evil in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php)

What you'd be better off doing is created a series of switch statements for all the various operations such as 'greater than', 'less than', 'equals' and so forth...

Comment: Alright so long story short I am doing it the right way. I just wanted to make sure that there wasn't something that I was missing with that. Thanks!

Comment: Actually thinking about this a bit more, eval() is considered a bad thing if the user has input as to what will go there correct? For this current situation I am using a select list with the presets of < > and ==. That being said perhaps using eval() is more of a logical answer?

Comment: If you are using a select list, then the user has input, in which case eval() should definitely not be used. Even though you are using a select box to restrict input, this is only pseudo-security as there is nothing to stop the user manipulating the HTML page with firebug or any other tool, changing the value of the options to some malicious code and then posting that form to your web server.

Comment: Very well then! Thanks for the information! I will stick with my orig way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do for this is to make a function call or object wrapper, and then call the function to achieve the same result.

Example:

```
$func = '__my_eq_op_';


if ($func($numb1,$numb2)) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

The operator functions are then...

```
function __my_eq_op($a,$b) {
  return $a == $b;
}

function __my_gte_op($a,$b) {
  return $a >= $b;
}

function __my_lte_op($a,$b) {
  return $a <= $b;
}
```

For example. So you can really just break it down into using the functions instead.

For this:

if ($x == $y)

The parser sees 6 tokens...
1) KEYWORD IF:
2) LPAREN
3) VAR X
4) EQ
5) VAR Y
6) RPAREN

The parser uses these tokens to construct the AST for the IF conditional. Your thinking needs to move away from seeing the "==" as a variable. It's an operator!

Comment: I think this answer would probably be another good way to go although I am not completely comfortable with functions yet. They are hard for me to get a grasp on in a way I think.

Comment: Nice idea +1, but the "stuff" will always be the same, I don't know how this could be useful...

Comment: There is not much else to do about it in general. The >= and <= operators are just that, operators. If you try and use them as variables how is the parser supposed to compute operator precedence?